# Logging and Reporting on W2k3 print server printing

Tags: windows, logging, printing, reporting

Simple setup, single Windows 2003 standard server running as a printer server.

Domain users have rights to print to all of the printers setup on the printer server.

Question:

I know the event log can log printing, but I'm looking for a detailed logging and reporting solution that can give me the following:

- user account that printed the print job
- time/date stamp
- print job details (number of pages, Kb size, filename/path printed)

I'd like to be able to report as follows:

- Date Reports (date or range)
- User report
- printer report
- (and of course combinations or sorting of the above)

Any suggestions or ideas on how to do this with 3rd party software or built-in software would be excellent, thanks!

Comment: +1 for the question - I've been looking for exactly the same thing, and it doesn't appear to exist.  I'll be watching this thread with interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Audit Windows 2003 print server usage](http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.com/2008/04/audit-windows-2003-print-server-usage.html) and [Auditing Windows 2003 Print Servers](http://pyreanspring.blogspot.com/2008/09/auditing-windows-2003-print-servers.html).